# Why is my op-amp integrator charging up to the DC voltage supplied (instead of the rails)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrator, miller-integrator

This is the op-amp integrator I am simulating. Theoretically I should get a ramp signal saturating at the op-amp rails, however I get the signal shown. Can anyone help me understand why?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't show the input...what is it? $$$$  Note the opamp is going to do whatever it has to to get it's two inputs to be the same voltage.   Maybe that will get you thinking...

Comment: It is a lowpass which can integrate only frequencies far above the pole frequency. You should select R5 as large as possible (from the offset point of view)

Comment: It is 3V. It will try to maintain 0V at both of it's inputs right. So, it will pump 3mA into the feed back loop. This current should charge the capacitor linearly right.

Comment: @LvW even when I adjust RC values, the shape changes but it saturates at -3V instead of 5V always.

Comment: You're powering this opamp from +/- 5 V, that's the bare minimum for this opamp, I would power it from at least +/- 10 V but since you're in a simulator I would use +/- 15 V so that the supply will not be an issue.

Comment: The DC gain of the circuit is unity (-R5/R6). hence, the maximum output cannot be more than the input voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the feedback resistor \$R_5\$ means that this is not a mathematically "ideal" op amp integrator, which would have infinite gain at DC. The circuit is a "practical" op amp integrator which takes into account the non-idealities of a real op amp (finite gain, input bias currents, output cannot exceed the power supplies, etc.). In a "practical" op amp integrator a feedback resistor is placed in parallel with the feedback capacitance, which lowers the DC gain and prevents the op amp from saturating at one of the power supply rails.

In this case the DC gain is $$-\frac{R_5}{R_6} = -1$$

This can be deduced by inspection, noting the fact that at DC a capacitor is an open circuit so at DC the capacitor can be removed and all you are left with is a simple inverting amplifier. Therefore, with a 3 V DC input the output is -3 V at steady state. If you increased the DC gain and/or reduced the power supply voltages and/or increased the DC input's amplitude then you would eventually see the op amp saturate. However, you generally want to avoid letting the op amp saturate so it's a good thing that this practical op amp circuit does not cause the op amp to saturate.